# Are there any Australian characters in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek

I've noticed we have quite a diversity of cultures throughout *Star Trek* canon, but I can't recall any characters who were (in-universe) from Australia.  **Are there any Australian characters in *Star Trek*?**

Comment: If you drop by Canada for the filming of the new Trek series and manage to become an extra, then *you* can be its Australian character. ;-)

Comment: @Praxis sounds like an important action to take to correct this massive oversight!

Comment: @Praxis I thought he was Omicron Thetan.

Comment: @amaranth : Born in Australia, settled on Omicron Theta.  ;-)

Comment: @Praxis exactly right 

Comment: They've joined us in every war we've started since WWII, and they quit on us now?!?!

Comment: I thought Olson, the ill-fated skydiving engineer from the 2009 movie, was Australian, but Memory Alpha says Northern England.

Comment: They all boldly bloody went to the beach mate.

Comment: I started a petition in the hopes of an Australian main character to be included in the new series, Star Trek: Discovery. I reckon it will be something new and fresh and if done right, relatable to those Australian Trekkies. Here's the link to the petition: https://www.change.org/p/cbs-television-studios-include-an-australian-as-one-of-the-main-characters-in-star-trek-discovery

Comment: Does Kirk's dad count? ;)

Comment: @RedCaio if you can find any evidence that he is Australian in universe (aside from his accent) then yes definitely. I'd even be willing to consider non-canonical sources if you could find one that establishes he is from the land down under!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *Star Trek* transcripts at [Chakoteya.net](http://www.chakoteya.net) mention only one fictional character from Australia. Any Terrans with unspecified places of birth could potentially have been born in Australia, but there’s no way to know for sure which ones.

## Hoshi Sato’s pen pal

[Hoshi Sato](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hoshi_Sato) had a pen pal from Brisbane. From the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/13.htm) to the *Enterprise* episode, “[Dear Doctor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dear_Doctor_(episode))”:

> **Hoshi**: I had a pen pal once when I was twelve, from Brisbane, Australia, and I loved getting her letters. It was like this little window into distant places with strange sounding names.

Her pen pal presumably would have been born around the year 2129, the year that Hoshi was born.

## Real-life people

There could be any number of real-life Australians who are known to exist in the *Star Trek* universe. Only one such person’s place of birth was mentioned in a script:

[Errol Flynn](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Errol_Flynn), a real-life actor from Australia, was mentioned in the *Deep Space Nine* episode, “[Past Tense, part II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Past_Tense,_Part_II_(episode))”. From the [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/458.htm):

> **Biddle Coleridge**: Errol Flynn was born in Tasmania. Look, you guys go where you want and I’ll go where I want, all right?

The [Australian Aborigines](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Australian_Aborigines) were mentioned in the *Voyager* episode, “[Waking Moments](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Waking_Moments_(episode))”.

Comment: "Strange sounding names..." - is Hoshi casting aspersions about our accents?!

Comment: @OftenRight Wollongong, Meekatharra, Warrnambool ... I rest my case.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that a personnel log seen on-screen lists Australia for someone, somewhere, or there could be an oblique reference to Australia that no one has recorded on Memory Alpha.

Answer (score 20):

Australian actor Wendy Hughes used her own Australian accent when she played Lieutenant Commander Nella Daren in Next Generation Season Six, Episode 19, so I just assumed her character was also Australian.

Answer (score 4):

## [Kyle](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kyle)

[image]

While it is not established on-screen, and the canonicity is dubious:

> Kyle was born on Earth. According to the comic book "Who's Who in Star Trek 1", he was born in Adelaide, Australia and his father was a sales representative for one of Earth's largest transportation companies. The novel Traitor Winds established his birthplace as Sydney, Australia.

However, there are contrary citations:

> For the Animated Series, he had a mustache and was voiced by James Doohan. The script for "Beyond the Farthest Star" mentioned that the character had to be voiced with a British accent.
>
> The video game Star Trek: Starship Creator mentioned that he was born in Sheffield, England in 2241.

Other characters appearing only in licensed novels or video games originated in Australia: [Tricia Cadwallader](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Tricia_Cadwallader), [Lester Foster](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Lester_Foster), and [Galarrwuy Nayingul](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Galarrwuy_Nayingul).